# Integrating silhouette v5.0 with Play 2.6

Tags: playframework-2.6, silhouette

I'am trying to integrate silhouette v5.0 with play 2.6 but i have an error while running the app, here is my build.sbt file and the error. thanhs for any help.

```
val buildVersion = "0.0.4"
 version := buildVersion
 resolvers += "Sonatype Staging" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/" 
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
guice,
 "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees" % "2.6.1",
 "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.4-fix26", "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.6.0",
"org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "3.2.2", 
"com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "5.0.0", 
"com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-password-bcrypt" % "5.0.0", 
"com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-crypto-jca" % "5.0.0", 
"com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-persistence" % "5.0.0", 
"com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-testkit" % "5.0.0" % "test" )
```

here is the error :

```
Unexpected exception

CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting method, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.ApplicationLoader$Context.lifecycle()Lplay/api/inject/DefaultApplicationLifecycle;
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule.$anonfun$apiBindings$1(ReactiveMongoModule.scala:25):
Binding(interface play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi to ProviderTarget(play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoProvider@4f6aa416)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

2) Error injecting method, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.ApplicationLoader$Context.lifecycle()Lplay/api/inject/DefaultApplicationLifecycle;
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule.$anonfun$apiBindings$1(ReactiveMongoModule.scala:22):
Binding(interface play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.modules.reactivemongo.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoProvider@4f6aa416)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

2 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I am was stuck on this play authentication with `2.6`. On finding no solution, what I did was make one from scratch using `Deadbolt2` with the help of my senior developer.

Here's is [link](https://github.com/datumbrain/play-authentication-starter) to git repository. Please `star`/`fork` it if you find this helpful.

Comment: Please add more explanation.

Comment: @Lithilion that didn't work for me. What did work is, you can see in the answer I updated.